# How to handle multiple thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, php, css, thumbnails, sprite

In my front page, I am fetching a BLOB that contains at least 40 images. This is somehow slows down my website. I am just wondering, is there anyway to handle this type of problems?

And also, I am using YSlow to check the overall performance of my website. My website did poor on "Make fewer HTTP requests" section; it is suggesting me to "This page has 44 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites." Are sprites really the appropriate solution for this?

Comment: You need to expand the question.  You say "This type of problem" - what's the problem? Loading 40 images, or getting them from your db?  When you mention sprites - they may be, but you again don't share the details of the application.  What are you doing with the thumbnails? If it's DB driven, then likely NO, sprites are not the solution, but does it need to be DB driven?  You've tagged this as javascript and php - are they the question, really? Or is it about the css, images, and sprites?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the question, this thumbnails are DB driven.

Comment: That much is obvious.  What's not obvious is *why* they are DB driven, and *what* you are doing with them.

Comment: I am creating a website basically the same as http://imgur.com/, if you go to their front page, you would notice they display the most viral ones in a form of thumbnails. I am trying to achieve the same effect. My problem is, whenever I display my thumbnails, the browser slows down, unlike imgur, it is super fast.

Comment: Have you run Yslow on that site? Does it report the same problems?

Comment: Yes, I have run Yslow on Imgur.com, the result I got was "This page has 12 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites." Obviously, those "12 external background images" are not the thumbnails it is displaying. Mine's caused is pure thumbnails.

Comment: So, sounds like youre loading those images from the db into background images, rather than just loading the image directly - is that right? If so, that's what's throwing the error, and is tricking Yslow - background images are usually static, not dynamically loaded from a db.  I'm sure there's nothing wrong with what you've got going on.